# DataTemplate disappears when moving items in ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a CellTemplate for a column in a ListView. The CellTemplate contains a ComboBox which has an ItemTemplate. Both ItemsSource and SelectedItem is bound to another ViewModel.
The ListView is bound to an ObservableCollection on a ViewModel. Above the ListView there is a toolbar with the buttons to move the selected item up and down. I buttons a bound to and ICommand which will make a Move on the ObservableCollection.

[image]

The view is updated fine, but the selected item in the ComboBox is not using the DataTemplate and is just showing the type name.

[image]

I found out that everything is working fine if IsEditable = false, but I need this to be true.

I have created a small project that verifies the problem. Perhaps this is an issue in WPF.

Here is XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication3:Item}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Width="100" IsEditable="true" TextSearch.TextPath="Name"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ToolBar>
            <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Up" Command="{Binding MoveItemUpCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            <Button Content="Down" Command="{Binding MoveItemDownCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </ToolBar>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand AddItemCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand MoveItemUpCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand MoveItemDownCommand { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Row> Collection { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<Row>();
        AddItemCommand = new RelayCommand(AddItem);
        MoveItemUpCommand = new RelayCommand<Row>(MoveItemUp, CanMoveItemUp);
        MoveItemDownCommand = new RelayCommand<Row>(MoveItemDown, CanMoveItemDown);
    }

    private bool CanMoveItemDown(Row arg)
    {
        if (arg == null)
            return false;

        return Collection.Last() != arg;
    }

    private void MoveItemDown(Row obj)
    {
        var index = Collection.IndexOf(obj);

        Collection.Move(index, index + 1);
    }

    private bool CanMoveItemUp(Row arg)
    {
        if (arg == null)
            return false;

        return Collection.First() != arg;
    }

    private void MoveItemUp(Row row)
    {
        var index = Collection.IndexOf(row);

        Collection.Move(index, index - 1);
    }

    private void AddItem()
    {
        Collection.Add(new Row());
    }
}

public class Row
{
    public Row()
    {
        Items = new List<Item> { new Item { Name = "Test1" }, new Item { Name = "Test2" } };
    }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Item SelectedItem { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What type name is displayed: `WpfApplication3.Row` or `WpfApplication3.Item`? Furthermore, I see that none of your ViewModels (including `Row` and `Item`) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`; does the problem also occur with `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: The text is displaying WpfApplication3.Item. It shouldn't be necessary to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in this case, because the view receives an OnCollectionChanged by the ObservableCollection.